# how to connect keyboard to harmonizer?

Tags: sound-effects

i have a yamaha p105 no MIDI out has USB TO HOST i thinking about a tc helicon harmony M for live gigs. Any suggestion on how to connect them without a laptop.  the harmony has MIDI in

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB Host -> Midi hardware converter.

The [Kenton](http://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/kenton-midi-usb-host) is the only one I'm aware of, though there may be others.
I've never used it personally, so I have no opinion on how well it does the job.

Comment: the yamaha p105 is not class compliant so the kenton will not work

Comment: Then I think you may struggle.

Comment: You're gonna need to connect the p105 to a computer, then connect the harmony-m to the computer using something like the Roland um-one.

As far as I know, you cannot connect them without the daw between them. Sorry